# SQLalchemy join on many-to-one relationship

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am totally stuck while trying to join an one to many relationship using SQLAlchemy.
My model looks like this:

```
class Protein(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'protein'

    protein_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    gene_name = Column(String(45))

    spectrum_hit_spectrum_hits = relationship(u'SpectrumHit', secondary='spectrum_protein_map')


class SpectrumHit(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'spectrum_hit'

    spectrum_hit_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)    
    sequence = Column(String(60, u'latin1_german1_ci'), index=True)
```

and the mapping table:

```
t_spectrum_protein_map = Table(
    'spectrum_protein_map', metadata,
    Column('spectrum_hit_spectrum_hit_id', ForeignKey(u'spectrum_hit.spectrum_hit_id'), nullable=False, index=True),
    Column('protein_protein_id', ForeignKey(u'protein.protein_id'), nullable=False, index=True)
)
```

And my query is:

```
query = DBSession.query(Protein.gene_name, SpectrumHit.sequence)
        query = query.join(SpectrumHit)
        result = query.all()
```

I also tried it the other way around

```
query = DBSession.query(SpectrumHit.sequence, Protein.gene_name)
        query = query.join(Protein)
        result = query.all()
```

If it helps i can also add my MySQL tables.

I always get the Error:

```
InvalidRequestError: Could not find a FROM clause to join from.  Tried joining to <class 'ligando.models.Protein'>, but got: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'spectrum_hit' and 'protein'.
```

Which explains itself...

If i try to do this query in plain MySQL it looks like this:

```
SELECT spectrum_hit.sequence, protein.gene_name
From spectrum_hit
join spectrum_protein_map on spectrum_hit.spectrum_hit_id = spectrum_protein_map.spectrum_hit_spectrum_hit_id
join protein on protein.protein_id = spectrum_protein_map.protein_protein_id
```

And it does work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your `metadata` object comes but if you change the mapping table code to use `Base.metadata`, your code will work:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Column, Table, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class Protein(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'protein'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    gene_name = Column(String(45))

    spectrum_hit_spectrum_hits = relationship('SpectrumHit', secondary='spectrum_protein_map')


class SpectrumHit(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'spectrum_hit'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    sequence = Column(String(60, u'latin1_german1_ci'), index=True)



spectrum_protein_map = Table(
    'spectrum_protein_map', Base.metadata,
    Column('spectrum_hit_id', ForeignKey('spectrum_hit.id')),
    Column('protein_id', ForeignKey('protein.id'))
)

eng = create_engine("mysql://<your connection string>", echo=False, pool_recycle=1800)
Base.metadata.create_all(eng)
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=eng, autocommit=False,autoflush=False)
session = session_maker()

res = session.query(Protein.gene_name, SpectrumHit.sequence).join(SpectrumHit).query.all()
```

Comment: My metadata object is declared globally in the file

metadata = Base.metadata

Comment: I've edit my response to include the whole script which works for me - can you spot any main differences?

Comment: I found the a solution by explicitly adding the mapping table into the join 
        query = query.join(t_spectrum_protein_map)

Thanks anyway! :)